# Jest, React Testing Library Async Await error

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library

React Js Code is

```
const AwaitAsync = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState("");
const handleClick = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setData("Data after 4 secons")
    }, 1000);
}

return (
    <div>
        <h2>Await Async</h2>
        <h4>Data will come after 4 secons</h4>
        <p>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Click to display data</button>
        </p>
        {
            data && <p data-testid="abc">{data}</p>
        }

    </div>
)
```

}

Unit test case is but unit test case is failed
Error is: let dat = await screen.findByTestId("abc");

```
describe('Async Await', () => { 

it("Async Await Test", async () => {
    // jest.setTimeout(10000);
    render(<AwaitAsync />);
    const btn = screen.getByRole('button');
    fireEvent.click(btn);
    let dat = await screen.findByTestId("abc");
    expect(dat).toHaveTextContent("Data after 4 secons")
});
```

})

Unit test case is failed

Answer (score 0):

You should [Enable Fake Timers](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks#enable-fake-timers)

> This is replacing the original implementation of `setTimeout()` and other timer functions.

See also [testing-recipes#timers](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#timers)

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { AwaitAsync } from '.';

describe('Async Await', () => {
  it('Async Await Test', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    render(<AwaitAsync />);
    const btn = screen.getByRole('button');
    fireEvent.click(btn);
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
    });
    expect(screen.getByTestId('abc')).toHaveTextContent('Data after 4 secons');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75395180/index.test.tsx (8.706 s)
  Async Await
    ✓ Async Await Test (76 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.22 s
```